# How can I limit my dygraph X axis to last 48 hours?

Tags: r, shiny, lubridate, dygraphs

I have a dygraph from a data source with datetime. The graph shows the full 12 days of data, however I'd like the X axis to only show the last 48 hours. I'm trying this:

```
library(lubridate)
...
dyAxis('x', valueRange = c(now()-days(2), now())
```

But I still get the full 12 days displayed on load.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dyRangeSelector` with `dateWindow` parameter:

```
# Generate data
library(data.table)
data = data.table(x=as.Date("2000-01-01")+0:10,y=0:10)

# Draw graph
library(dygraphs)

enddate = max(data$x)
startdate = enddate - 2
dygraph(data) %>% dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c(startdate,enddate))
```

[image]

`valueRange` only applies to y-axis.

Comment: This is great, I actually left my data in as datetime and just used seconds to get the 48 hrs. Didn't know that valueRange was only for y-axis!